# Need to add CSS to jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using this slider:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

I need to change the colors of slider handle & slider bar. Since I'm new to jQuery, I'm not able to figure out how to do it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I ran into the same problem and this is how I've solved it:

My html markup was this:

```
<div id="slider" class="hidden">
    <input type="text" id="sliderAmount" value="30% to 90%" readonly="readonly"/>               
</div>
```

I manually added the class to the handle bar with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider a").addClass("myClassForSliderHandle");
});
```

which, when you look at the code (inspect element in chrome) looks like this (because the jQueryUI turns the handle bar into the `a` tag):

```
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all myClassForSliderHandle" href="#"></a>
```

and I added this in my css file:

```
.myClassForSliderHandle {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

and this is the result I got:
[image]

Originaly, I was using theme [blitzer](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Arial,sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=6px&bgColorHeader=cc0000&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=15&borderColorHeader=e3a1a1&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityContent=75&borderColorContent=eeeeee&fcContent=333333&iconColorContent=cc0000&bgColorDefault=eeeeee&bgTextureDefault=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=d8dcdf&fcDefault=004276&iconColorDefault=cc0000&bgColorHover=f6f6f6&bgTextureHover=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=cdd5da&fcHover=111111&iconColorHover=cc0000&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=eeeeee&fcActive=cc0000&iconColorActive=cc0000&bgColorHighlight=fbf8ee&bgTextureHighlight=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcd3a1&fcHighlight=444444&iconColorHighlight=004276&bgColorError=f3d8d8&bgTextureError=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityError=75&borderColorError=cc0000&fcError=2e2e2e&iconColorError=cc0000&bgColorOverlay=a6a6a6&bgTextureOverlay=09_dots_small.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=65&opacityOverlay=40&bgColorShadow=333333&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=10&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px) which as you can see on this link doesn't have the yellow handlebars.

**edit:** how to change the slider color:
If you look at the class (I use inspect element in Chrome browser) which is applied to the slider you see this:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #E3A1A1;
    background: #C00 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_15_cc0000_1x100.png) 50% 50%         repeat-x;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now, in order to change the color of the slider you have to remove the background image, just try it like this (I tried and it works):

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #E3A1A1;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This class is located in the jQuery UI css file (in my case jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css).

Hope this now resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change scroll handle's color. But slider bar's color was not changed. Is it possible to change it's default color (even if slider is moved, slider bar's color remains same,say red for ex).

Comment: @benjamin54: please see my edit, I added the info on how to change the slider bar color too.

Comment: Okay I got it. I made changes to the class (.ui-widget-content) in CSS to achieve that.

Comment: @benjamin54: hehe, this was almost spot on reply when I updated my post :). Anyways, I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the css class to customize the color which you want or you have to apply the themes provided in the jquery. Try to change the theme in the right corner of the page  [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). It may useful for you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you is to use [jQueryUI themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Just create your own styles there and click on "Download Theme" when you're done. It will let you download your custom styled jQueryUI library.

Alternatively you will have to override CSS for specific jQueryUI classes, but it can become really complicated.

Comment: actually, I had the same exact problem and I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to change the handlebars - no option for that in the themeroller (*add this please jQueryUI if you're listening*), and I posted my answer as the "workaround" that worked for me.

Comment: @nikola, slider handles use styles from clickable section in jQueryUI Themeroller (default, hover and active state). [**Here**](http://tinyurl.com/9766da6)'s a theme with a slider that looks somewhat similar to what you have in your solution.